# Better way to write "like operator" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

Is there any better way to re-write the below code?

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROFILE 
WHERE GRP_NUMBER NOT LIKE '2%' AND GRP_NUMBER NOT LIKE '7%'
```

Comment: If that's what you need then that's the best you can do, at least with the information you've provided.  There are other ways, such as `left` string function, but they're all likely to perform the same.

Comment: @Nishant: what exactly you want to do?? Do you want to the speedup of query? or you want to use some other searching operators? or another operator instead of LIKE operator?? please specify your question

Comment: i want to speed up the query only with or without like operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below sample

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Col VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2ABC' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '4Italy2' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '3Apple' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '234.62' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2:234:43:22' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '7' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '6425.23'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Lions'


SELECT * FROM @Table
WHERE Col NOT LIKE '[27]%'
```

Comment: Why have you added a limitation disallowing a leading comma when no such constraint is present in the question?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Sorry, I have corrected that. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROFILE
WHERE GRP_NUMBER LIKE '[^27]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM PROFILE
  WHERE GRP_NUMBER NOT LIKE '[27]%'
```

Comment: Why don't you like leading commas?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks.I have edited the answer. PS: I have no aversion to leading commas. :)

Comment: Well, now it's spaces :-). It's simple - the characters enclosed in the `[]` brackets represent themselves, outside of a few special characters. Neither commas nor spaces are special here. Just don't add unnecessary characters into `LIKE` patterns.

Comment: Er..Thanks again.